# Ajax post Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Could not find where i am wrong. Here is my javascript code:

```
$(function() {
        function Confirme(commentid,status){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Management/Comment/Confirm',
                type: "POST",
                data: {"id": commentid,"status": status},
                success: function(response){
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

And here is view code:

```
<input type="button" value="Onayla" onclick="Confirme(52a17bc02b94b1c418000001,0)"   class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
```

No idea.

Comment: Is..."52a17bc02b94b1c418000001" what? for sure it's not an hex number and without quotes it's not a string...

Comment: The commentid does need to be surrounded with double quotes or single quotes also, as someone else answered and then deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Confirme` function is limited by its scope. Move it outside of the `$(function()` call:

```
    $(function() {

    });

    function Confirme(commentid,status){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Management/Comment/Confirm',
            type: "POST",
            data: {"id": commentid,"status": status},
            success: function(response){
            }
        })
    }
```

Also, as Adriano pointed out, you should wrap your commentid in quotes:

```
<input type="button" value="Onayla" onclick="Confirme('52a17bc02b94b1c418000001',0)"   class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
```